# How to add a table in PowerPoint using C# interop library?

Tags: c#

I'm dynamically creating a PowerPoint using C# and I need to create a table with variable rows and columns  The following code creates the table.

```
objShape = MySlide.Shapes.AddTable(10, 5, ConvertCmtoPx(4), ConvertCmtoPx(2.5), ConvertCmtoPx(15), ConvertCmtoPx(10));
table = objShape.Table;

for (int i = 1; i <= table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  for (int j = 1; j <= table.Columns.Count; j++)
  {
    table.Cell(i, j).Shape.Fill.Solid.SolidFill.BackColor.RGB = 0xffffff;
    table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 12;
    // table.Cell(i, j).Shape.Line.Style.BackColor.RGB = 0xFF3300;
    table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = PowerPoint.PpParagraphAlignment.ppAlignCenter;
    table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = MsoVerticalAnchor.msoAnchorMiddle;
    table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = string.Format("[{0},{1}]", i, j);
  }

}
```

---

Now, how to set the table border style?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following snippet inside your for loop to tweak the cell border thickness, line type, color, shading, etc.  There are a lot more items to choose from apart from DashStyle, ForeColor, etc.

```
table.Cell(i, j).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderLeft].DashStyle = MsoLineDashStyle.msoLineLongDashDot;
table.Cell(i, j).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderLeft].ForeColor.RGB = 0xff00ff;
table.Cell(i, j).Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpBorderType.ppBorderLeft].Weight = 1.0f;
```